# What are the differences regarding speed and functionality between using Actions vs Delegates?

Tags: c#

I know this is a language specific question and may not be suitable here but I would like to create an array of functions that will be called based on their index and I would like to know the difference between Delegates and Actions. I am aware that with delegates you string many of them in a single one and pass values between them etc. But are there any other differences?

Also are their any differences regarding speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Action is just a delegate thats predefined so you don't have to make them yourself when using Linq/PTL

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,486d58da4553e12d